# How replace \xe9 to é in a data frame column imported from a sql database?

Tags: r, character-encoding, shinydashboard

I have an issue with a data frame column which contains qualitative data like "Hérault". I imported these data with a sql query from a data base and the problem is that i get  "H\xe9rault" instead.

I need to have "Hérault" because it causes problem in my Shiny app ( I get <e9> for 'é' ) and i have no idea to resolve it. I tried to change encoding but didnt work.

```
con <- odbcConnect("HFSQLdb")
libdisp<-"select DISPOSITIF.Libellé,DISPOSITIF.IDDISPOSITIF
from DISPOSITIF"
libdisp<-sqlQuery(con,libdisp)
libdisp

                  libellé               IDDISPOSITIF
1       Logement - B\xe2t C                   1
2       Logement - B\xe2t B                   2
3       R\xe9s. Sociale                       3


>sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C            LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
 [1] rsconnect_0.8.28     DT_0.26              treemap_2.4-3       
 [4] chron_2.3-57         highcharter_0.9.4    forcats_0.5.2       
 [7] stringr_1.4.1        dplyr_1.0.10         purrr_0.3.4         
[10] readr_2.1.3          tidyr_1.2.1          tibble_3.1.8        
[13] tidyverse_1.3.2      viridis_0.6.2        viridisLite_0.4.1   
[16] scales_1.2.1         ggplot2_3.3.6        RODBC_1.3-19        
[19] odbc_1.3.3           DBI_1.1.3            shinydashboard_0.7.2
[22] shiny_1.7.2 



> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Please share `sessionInfo()` as well (or `Sys.getlocale()` at least…)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, i edited my question with what you asked. I'm new here sorry if it's not perfect

Comment: You do not share `odbcConnect` in your MRE; I'd try setting `DBMSencoding` to latin1 (or alike), see [sqlQuery: Query an ODBC Database](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-19/topics/sqlQuery). Tested on hardcoded value: `x<-"H\xe9rault"; c(x,Encoding(x), uchardet::detect_str_enc(x))` returns `[1] "H\xe9rault" "unknown" "ISO-8859-1"`

Comment: I tried 'DBMSencoding="Latin-1"' in the odbcConnect but i get                                             'Error in iconv(query, to = enc) : unsupported conversion from '' to 'Latin-1' in codepage 65001'